# Amazon Lightsail database data transfer cost, when connecting from EC2

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-lightsail

I'm new on the Lightsail Database and RDS services, and I've a doubt about transfer costs

while for RDS, I've read around quite clearly that traffic from/to the RDS instance is free, as long as it is generated via its private address...

..for Lightsail Database, I cannot see anywhere its private address (despite normal Ligtsail instances, that have both private and public IP addresses).
It seems that Lightsail Database instances has not a private IP address

so my questions are:

- am I right, Ligthsail database doesn't have public IP?
- if so, if I connect to a Lightsail Database from an EC2 instance of mine (on the same zone) using the endpoint URL, does it generate traffic costs?

I'm wondering if it is possible to connect to a Lightsail Database from an EC2 instance, without traffic cost, as it happens for RDS, using private IP